# ¿Como se crean las llaves primarias compuestas desde la migraciones en TypeOrm?

Tags: typeorm, nestjs

Estoy creando unas tablas desde las migraciones en NestJs usando TypeOrm, pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo desde el API para las migraciones de TypeOrm.

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
await queryRunner.createTable(
  new Table({
    name: 'dish_ingredients',
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'dish_id',
        type: 'bigint',
        isPrimary: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'ingredient_id',
        type: 'bigint',
        isPrimary: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'is_active',
        type: 'bool',
        default: true,
      },
    ],
  }),
);
```

}

Este el código que tengo ya para crear la tabla, pero no he podido avanzar más porque no encuentro información de esto en los doc de TypeOrm

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer esto
@Entity('tabla')
@Index(['unidad_id', 'suplidor_id'], { unique: true })
export class precios extends BaseEntity

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código._ Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Gracias, Luis, ya había resuelto el problema.